# Javascript variable problem

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings in Javascript that I need to use to load images in my page via AJAX. After each image is loaded, I need to perform some additional tasks such as sending a HTTP request which will actually delete the image.

This is what I have so far.

```
for (x in images) {
    var img = new Image();
    $(img)
        .load(function(){
            $('#image_'+images[x]).html(''); //remove loading gif
            $('#image_'+images[x]).append(this);
            $.post('/images/destroy_image',{id:images[x]});
        })
        .attr('src', '/images/get_image?id='+images[x]);
}
```

This code works fine if there is only 1 string in the `images` array.

If there is more than 1, when an image finishes loading and its `load` function is run, any reference to `images[x]` in its `load` function now point to the final string in the `images` array, when I need it to be the value it was when the loop was being run.

Eg.

`images` is `{'12','100'}`

When the first image finishes loading, the first line in its `load` function will be run as

```
$('#image_100').html('');
```

when it should be

```
$('#image_12').html('');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Fyi, you can use `$('<img/>')` instead of the `new Image()` stuff.

Comment: *`images` is `{'12','100'}`*. That would result in a syntax error. I hope you mean `['12','100']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery's `each()` function closes over each value in the array, so you don't end up with a reference to just the last value:

```
$.each(images, function(i,v) {
    var img = new Image();
    $(img)
        .load(function(){
            $('#image_'+v).html(''); //remove loading gif
            $('#image_'+v).append(this);
            $.post('/images/destroy_image',{id:v});
        })
        .attr('src', '/images/get_image?id='+v);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Typical *function-in-a-loop* problem. You have to "capture" the current value of `x` by introducing a new scope (through a function, does not have block scope). You could do:

```
function loadImage(image) {
    $('<img />')
        .load(function(){
            $('#image_'+image).html(''); //remove loading gif
            $('#image_'+image).append(this);
            $.post('/images/destroy_image',{id:image]});
        })
        .attr('src', '/images/get_image?id='+image);
}

for (var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++) { // it seems `images` is an array 
    loadImage(images[i]);
}
```

[Don't use a `for...in` loop to iterate over arrays.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: JavaScript also has global scope, `try`-`catch` scope and `eval` scope.

Comment: @katspaugh: *global scope*: yeah kind of. It's just properties of the global object (it's not really "scope"). *`try`-`catch`* scope: What do you mean exactly? How does this introduce scope? `eval` scope: No, `eval` is evaluated in the current scope.

Comment: `catch` takes an argument, which is local to the `catch` block. `eval` I don't understand as clearly. I was referring to the `eval` oddities described in http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-2-strict-mode/#indirect-eval-call

Comment: @katspaugh: Regarding `catch`: yes, the argument is indeed local to the block, but if you define a "local" variable inside the `catch` block (`var x = ...`), then this one is local to the outer function, not to that block. Regarding `eval`: I don't have the time to read all this... maybe later ;)

Comment: It basically says that there's "indirect `eval` call", like `(1, eval('...'))` which executes in the global scope.

Comment: @katspaugh: `eval` itself cannot *create* scope. It is a matter of *in which* scope the expression is evaluated but it is always in an existing scope. Either global or local.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a traditional for loop, so you can have a counter. I think the "x" in your foreach loop is the actual object and not the index value, but you use it like an index elsewhere. Does that fix it?

Comment: No, `x` is the index (or property name), not the value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: My understanding is that "images" contained an array of numbers, like 12,100,5 etc, so calling images[x] within the loop would be images[12]. I could be wrong, I never was great at loops

Comment: Your understanding of `images` is correct, but `x` will not be the value. `for...in` iterates over the *properties* of an object, which, if it is an array, happens to be the array indexes. Have a look at the link I posted...

Answer (score 0):

You're running into this issue due to some semantic discrepancies that exist between the way closures are frequently explained and the way they actually work in most languages.  Without getting into that topic, you may have better luck with:

```
for (var index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
    var img = new Image();
    $(img)
        .load(load(images[index]))
        .attr('src', '/images/get_image?id='+image);
}

function load(image) {
    return function() {
        $('#image_'+image).html(''); //remove loading gif
        $('#image_'+image).append(this);
        $.post('/images/destroy_image',{id:image});
    };
}
```

If you want to get into the topic of why this works where the previous example failed, closures are often explained as creating a snapshot of the state that exists in the current lexical scope.  This is a somewhat misleading analogy, because unlike a true snapshot which is immutable, the state inside of the closure continues to live and can be modified by things that happen outside of the closure.

Case in point, when you do something like:

```
for (x in myArray) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(myArray[x]);
    }, 2000);
}
```

...there is only a single variable instance referred to by `x`, and the closure is capturing a *reference* to `x` as opposed to a snapshot of the current value of `x`.  Thus when subsequent iterations modify the value of the single instance of `x` that exists in this scope, the change appears in every closure that was created with a reference to `x`.

And it works when you do:

```
for (x in myArray) {
    var item = myArray[x];
    setTimeout(makeClosure(item), 2000);
}

function makeClosure(value) {
    return function() {
        alert(value);
    };
}
```

...because a different variable reference is created on each iteration (by calling `makeClosure()`), and once created the value is never modified.  Each closure that is created carries a reference to the most recently defined value, and thus appears to "remember" the correct value later on when it executes.

Comment: This will not help either. By the time the `load` callback runs, `image` will have the value of the last iteration. JS does not have block scope (so it's like declaring `image` before the loop).

Comment: *because a different `item` variable is created on each iteration* no, it is not (not in JavaScript) and that's why it does not work.

Comment: @Felix - Yes, it's fixed now.  A bit surprised about there being no lexical scope for the block, but jsfiddle confirmed that quickly enough.

Comment: Yes, that is one of JavaScript's quirks. All variable and function declarations are hoisted to the beginning of the containing scope... and blocks do not create a new scope.